# Berkeley DB optimization

Tags: optimization, berkeley-db

I am using berkeley DB to solve a message queue, but I found out that after the queue raised to some size, the read speed went down fastly, I guess it's because it started to write on hard disk, is there anyway to improve the reading speed?

Comment: As far as I know Berkley DB isn't an in-memory DB. Do you use the Queue access method or the standard BTree? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg/JAVA/accessmethods.html

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same experience with Berkeley DB. After searching and experimenting on a strategy I have found it relatively effective and efficient. You have to ensure building a database in chunks as possible on a full speed, remember that it should not be as large as 1 million records. Now, open the cursor over the chunk and insert the records into new database in a sorted order. Hope you will be able to build a supreme database in this way.

Comment: yes,the data I put in are in a sorted order always, now I wonder whether it would get better if I add the secondary database.